# Tkinter window font to expand dynamically while stretching the window

Tags: python, tkinter, font-size

I have created a Tkinter GUI and I would like to make the font expand while the window is expanding. I have tried so far weights, but only the window expands and not the letters. In the following script is an example of the code I am trying to create.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import *


master = tk.Tk()
#Title of GUI
master.title("Test Name")
#Seperate first GUI tab in sections

stepOne = tk.LabelFrame(master, text=" 1. General Heatmaps: ")
stepOne.grid(row=0, columnspan=7, sticky='WE', \
             padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

master.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
master.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

# this wil create a label widget 
l1 = Label(stepOne, text = "Input tilt:") 
l2 = Label(stepOne, text = "Input wind speed:") 
l3=  Label(stepOne, text = "Input path:") 
# grid method to arrange labels in respective 
# rows and columns as specified 
l1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = E, pady = 2) 
l2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E, pady = 2) 
l3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = E, pady = 2)

entryTilt = Entry(stepOne)
entryWind = Entry(stepOne)
entryFolder_path=Entry(stepOne)

entryTilt .grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 2) 
entryWind .grid(row = 2, column = 1, pady = 2) 
entryFolder_path .grid(row = 3, column = 1, pady = 2)  

b1 = Button(stepOne, text = "Run script") 

b1.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = E) 

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change the font size instead of the layout,right?

Comment: Yes, this is my goal

Comment: Do you want to change the font size of everything, or only certain widgets?

Comment: The font size is the original target, but I would like to see how it would look if i changed everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import *
# from tkinter.ttk import *

wh_font_map = {k: v for k, v in zip(range(200, 1900, 50), range(10, 44))}
# {
#   200: 10,
#   250: 11,
#   300: 12,
#   350: 13,
#   400: 14,
#   450: 15,
#   500: 16,
#   550: 17,
#   600: 18,
#   650: 19,
#   700: 20,
#   750: 21,
#   800: 22,
#   850: 23,
#   900: 24,
#   950: 25,
#   1000: 26,
#   1050: 27,
#   1100: 28,
#   1150: 29,
#   1200: 30,
#   1250: 31,
#   1300: 32,
#   1350: 33,
#   1400: 34,
#   1450: 35,
#   1500: 36,
#   1550: 37,
#   1600: 38,
#   1650: 39,
#   1700: 40,
#   1750: 41,
#   1800: 42,
#   1850: 43
# }
def change_font(event):
    font_size = wh_font_map[next(k for k in wh_font_map if (master.winfo_width() + master.winfo_height()) / 2 <= k)]
    for widget in stepOne.winfo_children():
        widget['font'] = ("", font_size)


master = tk.Tk()
# Title of GUI
master.title("Test Name")
# Seperate first GUI tab in sections

stepOne = tk.LabelFrame(master, text=" 1. General Heatmaps: ")
stepOne.grid(row=0, columnspan=7, sticky='WE', \
             padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

# master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
# master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# this wil create a label widget
l1 = Label(stepOne, text="Input tilt:")
l2 = Label(stepOne, text="Input wind speed:")
l3 = Label(stepOne, text="Input path:")
# grid method to arrange labels in respective
# rows and columns as specified
l1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E, pady=2)
l2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E, pady=2)
l3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E, pady=2)

entryTilt = Entry(stepOne)
entryWind = Entry(stepOne)
entryFolder_path = Entry(stepOne)

entryTilt.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2)
entryWind.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=2)
entryFolder_path.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=2)

b1 = Button(stepOne, text="Run script")

b1.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=E)
master.bind("<Configure>", change_font)
master.mainloop()
```

---

Just an idea.

My idea:

1. Bind an event for the window.
2. Get the average of the height and the width of the window.Use the dict `wh_font_map` to get the font size.(You could change the range)

The `wh_font_map` will generate a `average-font size`mapper.You could change it manually.

---

Set the font size of the `ttk.Button` needs to use `ttk.Style()`.
For convenience, I change it to `tk.Button`.If you really need to use `ttk.Button()`.Read about [ttk-Style](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html)